# Looping through django model and inserting values

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a model product :

```
class Product (models.Model):
    fk_subcat2=models.ForeignKey(SubCategory2)
    fk_seller=models.ForeignKey(User)
    name=models.CharField("Product Name",max_length=100)
    quantity=models.IntegerField("Product Quantity",default=0)
    active= models.BooleanField("Product Active or Not", default=False)
    price=models.FloatField("Price", default=0.0)
    selling_price=models.FloatField("Selling Price", default=0.0)
    tax=models.FloatField("Tax", default=0.0)
    shipping_charges=models.FloatField("Shipping Charge", default=0.0)
    cod_options=models.BooleanField("Cash on delivery options" , default=False)
    brand= models.CharField("Brand/Manufacturer",max_length=100)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False, unique=True, default=get_unique_id_str)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('Date created', default=timezone.now)
    date_updated= models.DateTimeField('Date updated',auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I made an excel sheet for bulk uploading of products.
Now what I want is dynamic product save i.e. I want to loop through the model
fields(except fk_subcat2 and fk_seller) and insert values in it.
What I have done is :

```
for i in range(7):
    data1 = b[i]
    prod = Product(fk_subcat2=category_instance, fk_seller=request.user)
    prod.data1 = c[i].value
    prod.save()
```

where b[] contains all the model fields(e.g. : name,quantity,price etc etc) and c[] contains values related to b[] (e.g. : Apple iphone 5s,5,300 $ etc etc)..

Tried using this procedure but it never works.Might be having problem with the name **prod.data1**.

Any solutions ????

Comment: What's the error message? What error do you get? What does *it never works* mean?

Comment: No error message..But values are not inserting as I want it to.. a new product is created whenever this code is executed with only fk_seller and fk_subcat2 values. Other field remaining blank...

Comment: I don't see `data1` field in the `Product` model. Sure it's not going to be persisted in the db.

Comment: After inserting ???

Comment: Where `data1` field? Is it created on-the-fly. If so, it will be alive during object's lifetime and won't be stored in the db. You gotta create a field like `data1 = models.CharField(...)`

Comment: Trying it out. Thanks

Comment: You can't access to all fields by passing an array instead of the attribute name.

Comment: Trying to pass it as a python dictionary  @sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can merge field names and values in one dictionary, named `kwargs` for example:

```
Product.objects.create(fk_subcat2=category_instance, fk_seller=request.user, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying it out

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with calling `.create()`. Calling `.save()` does the same thing as `prod` has not yet been created.

Comment: @ozgur at first, `.create()` is the common shortcut for `obj = Object()`, `obj.field_name = value`, `obj.save()`. At second, a key part of the answer is `kwargs`.